# Do other client interface than web for Stackoverflow exists

Tags: feature-request

Do other client interface than web for Stackoverflow exists

If not

Could it be good to have

- nntp New group interface, So people can use their favorit news client to question and answer.
- Or its own RIA (Rich Internet Application) client both for Terminal and/or Graphical.

Comment: Check out http://stackapps.com/ for other applications. NOTE that these are **read only** at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://stackapps.com for API, apps, and scripts.